# How to calculate Averages with Ruby's Inject feature

Tags: ruby, coding-style, iteration, average

I think that Ruby's `inject` method is really neat for calculating sums. But if I have to calculate an average and use `inject`, I always end up with something like this:

```
total_ranked_query_results = @results.count { |result| result.class == RankedQueryResult }
@results.inject(0.0) { |sum, result| result.class == RankedResult ? sum + result.average_precision : sum } / total_ranked_query_results
```

So I basically have to iterate twice to find out how many `RankedResults` there are in order to calculate the average.

Is there any better (rubyesque) way of avoiding this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either do the count and sum in the same iteration:

```
tmp = @results.inject([0.0, 0]) { |sum, result|
    if RankedResult === result
        [sum.first + result.average_precision, sum.last+1]
    else
        sum
    end
}
tmp.first / tmp.last
```

Or first filter the collection:

```
tmp = @results.filter { |result| RankedResult === result }
tmp.inject(0.0) { |sum, result| sum+result.avergage_precision } / tmp.length
```

Comment: In the first example the tmp.last is calculated incorrectly, it should be incremented only when result is RankedResult